# Grouping but not mutually exclusive in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a tablix like so

Two parameters - begin date and end date

```
Customer   Emp Hires    Emp Terminations
 XYZ        12          2
```

What's the best way to do the grouping, specifically the column grouping? I'm currently grouping by customer in the row group and then in the hire field, I'm doing a `sum(iif(hire_date between begin and end date,1,0))`. Same for termination field but using the employee's termination date. (Essentialy a `sum(case when then 1 else 0 end)` in SQL

Now, since they may run it for an entire month, an employee might fall in both columns (hired and termed in the same month). Is what I'm doing the best way or is there a more correct/more effient way? If what I'm doing is the best way in SSRS, it seems I should do the pivoting in SQL (if possible) instead for better performance overall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server,I would suggest to perform this grouping in SQL query only by passing date parameters as the SQL processing is quite fast than that of SSRS.

This is my personal experience to improve performance of report.

Comment: If I don't have access to the underlying query (I usually do but assuming I don't), would this be the best way in SSRS?

Comment: Yes if the database in not your control then grouping in SSRS is the only option.I would suggest to use the Between function carefully in SSRS and check for the overlaping dates in diffrent labels. But i would still suggest you can modify SQL quries faster than that in SSRS and for that you dont require special permissions read only will work.